# Firestore Is deleting Data on Flutter when new data added

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hi i am developing an app i have a listview i just created on tap method when user clicked to the item on listview it saves details to the firestore but when user  clicked other item it deletes current one and adding item  which is clicked  i just want to keep all clicked item on firestore if you have any suggestions please let me know thanks

this is first clicked item
[image]

[image: this is second clicked item it keeps always last clicked data]

this is second clicked item it keeps always last clicked data]

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
    await transaction.set(Firestore.instance.collection("cart").document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd"), {
      foodItem.name : {
        'itemName': foodItem.name,
        'imgUrl': foodItem.imageAssetPath,
        'itemPrice': foodItem.price,
        'quantity': '1',
      }
    });});
```

Comment: You should use update or add, instead of set, try it, if it works I will submit whole answer.

Comment: update is worked thanks a lot

Comment: also how can i check if data is available in document for example if data is available in firabase i just want to increase  quantity

Comment: Please, you should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked in comments lately, you should use `update` instead of `set` as you want to let the old data without deletion in the same document.

Also, maybe full [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) helps you to find out more problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd")`, so you will edit that particular item. If you try to create a new item with the same id `LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd`, it substitute the old item with the new.

You have to let Firebase Firestore create the a new document id automatically for you, or you have to give a unique id yourself.